# Wagtail - How to save a record which uses InlinePanel containing M2M

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a model which uses an `InlinePanel` to reference another model (`ClubTimetable`) which itself contains an M2M relationship to `DayOfTheWeek`. It seems as though I am unable to save the record because `ClubTimetable` is not yet saved and cannot create the M2M relationship to `DayOfTheWeek`, causing the following error:

`"<ClubTimetables: Club Timetable (str) 18:00:00>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

What can I do to solve this issue?

My models look like this

```py
# ClubManager

@register_snippet
class ClubManager(ClusterableModel):

    name = models.CharField('Club name',
                            max_length=255,
                            help_text='The name of the club.')

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        InlinePanel('club_timetable', heading='Timetable Information')
    ]
```

```py
# ClubTimetables

class ClubTimetables(Orderable, AddressBase):

    attached_to = ParentalKey(
        'club.ClubManager', related_name='club_timetable')

    weekday = models.ManyToManyField(DaysOfTheWeek)

    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    panels = [ ... ] + AddressBase.panels
```

```py
# DaysOfTheWeek

class DaysOfTheWeek(models.Model):

    weekday = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.weekday
```

Visually, it looks like this

**(Initial)**
[image: Initial view]

**(Adding timetable)**
[image: After adding timetable]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it works inside an InlinePanel, but you should try ParentalManyToManyField rather than a plain ManyToManyField: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#categories

Comment: I gave this a go, the model saves without error however the M2M relationship does not. Even if I go back to a record and add a day in it still does not save.

Comment: I am running into the same problem. The Many to Many field is not being saved.

Comment: @DanielButler There might be a way around it, it's down to the order the saving happens for the models and I played around with it for a short while but couldn't get it to work. In the end, I just restructred the models so it wouldn't rely on nested M2Ms

Comment: I did the same thing. After awhile I just switched to a Clusterable class that handles the many to many relationship with a reference between each keys and used the InlinePanel to handle editing in wagtail. Nothing about my problem space required me to use a ManyToMany field so I didn't spend much time on attempting to get it to work.